# It was I or it is I (or both since it is just a matter of perspectives)

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-tense, sequence-of-tenses, consequence

This confusion has been haunting me since I was fifteen. Please consider the following:
A. It **was** I who killed your mom.
B. It **is** I who killed your mom.

Question: **As far as I know, we can apply two points of view here; the one of the past and that of the present, so we may use either *was* or *is* as long as *I* is still alive. Am I right?**

Comment: Neither version is "wrong".  As you say, it depends on the point of view implied by the context.

Comment: Where do you see any confusion, please? Either way, does "since I was 15" mean one or two, or 20 or 30 years?

It is not at all a matter of perspectives.

No, you may not use either was or is as long as I is still alive. You are not right and you should, please, take this Question to English Language Learners.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin sorry, but it seems you got it totally wrong, Sir. The first sentence there is just the intro to the point. The sentences to consider are the A and B sentences. The question is the one in bold type.

Comment: @Fadli Sheikh Thanks and if you must put it that way no, you not I got it wrong, Sir.

Broadly, "It was I…" would be acceptable. "It is I…" would not.

The correct "I killed (whoever)…" is simply not comparable to "It is I who killed (whoever)…"

If you doubt that, why not try the same Question in English Language Learners, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either can be correct in the right context.

You *were* the person who killed their mother, and you still *are* the person who killed their mother.

> "Who killed my mom?"
> "I **did**."
> → It **was** I who killed killed your mom.
>
> "Who **is** the person who killed my mom?"
> "I **am**."
> → It **is** I who killed your mom.

---

Having said that, if there is no such exchange of dialogue to set the context, and each sentence is being offered as an unsolicited statement, then the past-tense version would be much more likely to make sense.

The present-tense version is jarring on its own, because the murder happened in the past. So, as a simple utterance, the past tense better matches the past event.

Using *it **is** I* only makes sense in response to a previous present-tense question that sets the stage, so to speak, for a present-tense reply. In fact, it would actually be jarring to hear a past-tense reply to a present-tense question.

If the statement is a reply to a question, then whichever tense the question is asked in would normally be the tense that it's answered in.

Comment: Never have I got so clear an explanation before! Thanks a lot :)